# Problems lazy loading during IValidatableObject's Validate method

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, navigation-properties

I'm using EF4.3, POCOs, Lazy Loading and the IValidatableObject interface.

I have a loan entity with a 1-1 relationship with a contract entity.  Contract contains a bunch of data that is best left unloaded unless required.

My problem is... When I make changes to my loan entity, it's Validate method is meant to load the related contract entity to ensure it's data is valid according to the state (or status) of the loan... but the contract navigational property remains null?  If I quickwatch the loan immediately before SaveChanges is called, the contract data is loaded and SaveChanges proceeds fine, otherwise it fails.

If someone is able to explain why I am seeing this behavior, I would be most grateful.

Cheers

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is turned off by design (internal EF implementation) during validation to avoid unexpected queries to database. If your validation logic requires related entity your code should load it.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav.  This answers my question perfectly.  Not really what I wanted to hear, but now I know what the problem is.

Comment: Is this behavior set in stone?  Is there any way to turn it on?

Comment: EF is now open source so you can download the codebase and modify it for your case.